# Need to show a card widget and after some delay automatically show another card widget regarding google workspace add-on creation

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I need to show homeCard() and after I need to show settingsCard() automatically. Since I coudn't find a right method in app-script documentation I need some help for do this task.

**Here I provided the code**

```
function nevigateToUserSelectionPage(e) {
  
  var navigation = CardService.newNavigation();
  var builder = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder();

  var userSelectionCardNavigation = navigation.pushCard(settingsCard());

  return builder.setNavigation(userSelectionCardNavigation).build();
}
```

```
function homeCard() {

  builder = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  section = CardService.newCardSection();

  let participantsText = CardService.newTextParagraph()
      .setText("<u>Home card here</u>");

  let blink = CardService
    .newImage()
    .setImageUrl('https://res.cloudinary.com/deez2bddk/image/upload/v1646709349/icons8-dots-loading_x9q7jv.gif');

  section.addWidget(blink);
  section.addWidget(participantsText);
  section.addWidget(AddSplah);
 

  builder.addSection(section);
  console.log('home card triggered!!!');

  return builder.build();
}
```

```
function settingsCard() {
  
  //const myTimeout = setTimeout(5000);
 Utilities.sleep(10000);
  builder = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  section = CardService.newCardSection();

  console.log('Settings card triggered!!!');

  let participantsText = CardService.newTextParagraph()
      .setText("<u>This is Settings Page....</u>");

  section.addWidget(participantsText);
  section.addWidget(getAuthenticationStepperImage());

  
  builder.addSection(section);
  
  return builder.build();
}
```

in code.gs file

```
function mainController() {
  return homeCard();  
}
```

Above code blocks I need to execute homeCard() function and then , settingsCard() but I can`t find a proper solution in workspace add-on creation documentation provided by google.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I think the  [`CardService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service) does not provide a method for non-interactive updates.

You can update the view based on user click interaction, as you can see in the [Cats Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/cats-quickstart). When the user clicks the cat image changes the image updates due the URL has a new parameter via `new Date().getTime()`.

Apart from this, you have the triggers provided by Google, such as:  [`homepageTrigger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/homepage-trigger#homepagetrigger) for common use case or [`onItemsSelectedTrigger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/drive-addons#onitemsselectedtrigger) specifically for Drive. You can review the full list [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons).

**In summary**: I think that what are you trying to achieve actually is not currently feasible within [`CardService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service).

If you wish Google adds some kind of time driven trigger to Google Workspace Add-ons, request it via this [form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206).

Remember that in the actual state, [HTML/CSS is not allowed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/workspace-restrictions#_use_htmlcss_or_client-side_scripting), maybe this would be another possible path for your Feature Request.